# Resolvent in random matrix theory

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, random-matrices

The Stieltjes transform method is a technique to understand the spectrum of a random matrix.  On the way to proving a local semicircle law with this technique, one encounters the stieltjes transform of the semicircle law, which is defined as
$$
m(z) := \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\rho}{x - z} dx
$$
where $\rho = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sqrt{(4 - x^2)_+}$.  One can show that $m(z)$
satisfies the equation 
$$
m(z)  + 1/ m(z)  + z = 0
$$
with Im(z) > 0.  One can solve for $m(z)$ to find that
$$
m(z)  = \frac{-z + \sqrt{z^2 - 4}}{2}. 
$$
Now it is claimed that for $x \in [-20, 20]$ and $y \in (0, 20]$ that for $z = x + i y$,

1) There is a constant $c > 0$ such that
$$
 c \leq |m(z)| \leq 1 - cy
$$

2) There exist constants $C', c' >0$ such that
$$
c' \sqrt{\kappa + y} \leq |1 - m^2(z)| \leq C' \sqrt{ \kappa + y}
$$
where $\kappa := ||x| - 2|$.

3) Also for $|x| \leq 2$, there exist constants $C'', c''>0$ such that 
$$
c'' \sqrt{\kappa + y} \leq Im(m(z)) \leq C'' \sqrt{\kappa + y}.
$$

4) For $|x| \geq 2$, 
$$
c'' \frac{y}{\sqrt{\kappa + y}} \leq Im(m(z)) \leq C'' \frac{y}{\sqrt{\kappa + y}}.  
$$

I can show the explicit form of $m(z)$ , but
I'm having difficulty demonstrating any of the 4 properties.  Any suggestions or explicit calculations would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you my thoughts on 4).  Let $z = x + i y$ then
$$
Im(\frac{-z + \sqrt{z^2 - 4}}{2}) = -y/2 + Im(\sqrt{x^2 - y^2 + 2xy i})/2.
$$
This should just be a brute force calculation and there is an explicit formula for the imaginary part of a square root.  I can't guarantee this is the correct approach.

Comment: Not really that helpful, but since nobody else seems to be taking interest, I'll award you the bounty.